# Access 2007 Export Report to Auto-Generated PDF Form

Tags: javascript, vba, forms, ms-access, pdf

Basically, I would like to know if it's possible to do the following:

- Export Report to PDF
- Create Adobe Acrobat object for creating fillable PDF Forms
- Go through PDF, placing fields over prices
- Create calculated fields in certain locations (adding/dividing other fields on PDF Form)
- Allow for recipient to insert logos into PDF Form
- Save PDF Form
- Notify Access end user that export to PDF Form was a failure/success

Here's some snippets of the report I will be exporting to this PDF Form:

[image]

[image]

Wherever you see a dotted line, the "MSRP" location (first page), discounts and other spots is where I would want plain fields. "Total Options & NPOs", "Gross Cost" and such will be calculated fields, adding/dividing "MSRP" and dotted line plain fields.

I'm already quite well-versed in VBA but not so much in JavaScript (which is what Acrobat uses when it comes to creating PDF Forms). Acrobat also has ODBC connectivity from what I've read thus far too on Adobe webpages.

Is this too far-fetched of an idea, even with VBA/JavaScript and the appropriate Acrobat references?

Like I said earlier, I'm not looking for complete code wrapped up in the nice, convenient package (since this is quite a custom feature), but if anyone can point me in the right direction... it will more than help!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a msAccess Report and export it to Pdf with:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192065.aspx

an example:

```
Dim fso, strTempPath 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strTempPath = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2)  
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "YOUR_MSACCESS_BWS_REPORT_NAME", acFormatPDF, strTempPath & "\YOUR_FILENAME.pdf", False
```

Comment: Okay, but would I then generate a fillable pdf form using this pdf and the Adobe Acrobat object? The pdf exportation isn't what's getting me, the unknown for me is the pdf form creation from VBA.